# Is this a ceiling fan box?

Tags: electrical, ceiling, ceiling-fan

This is a picture of the box and a ceiling of my office. It looks to me like a ceiling fan box as it has a metal brace going out either side and a large bolt holding it to the brace. This room is pretty old and I couldn't see a weight rating on the box so I just wanted someone else to give their opinion.

Is this a ceiling fan box?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is most likely yes. The bar runs between the joists and the nut in the center of the box means it has overhead support. The main thing is that a lot of boxes were mounted only to one joist and could not support the weight of a heavy fixture like a fan.

The [retrofit box](http://www.homedepot.com/p/15-5-cu-in-Retrofit-Ceiling-Fan-Saf-T-Brace-0110000/204845572) you would install if it wasn't is simply to add that support arm.

Answer (score 0):

With a nut that beefy, yes it will support a fan. Braces are used in many ceiling boxes, however if they were meant to only support a light fixture there would two philips head screws at the back of the box to clamp down on a thinner and lighter brace.  Put a socket wrench on the nut and make sure that it's tight before installing your fan.